# SQL join or merge results?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Look at this DB schema:

[image: DB Schema]

The users can order products. For any order I add a new record in the *orders* table and a new record in *orders-products* N:M table for any single product ordered by the user (and fill pieces field). But, when a user creating an order, I need to show the list of **all products** and fill the pieces field with the quantity ordered for any product.

Usually, to do it, I use two queries.
The first query get all products in the *products* table:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

The second query gets the products ordered in the *orders-products* table **filtering** them by *orders-idorder* FK:

```
SELECT orders_idorder AS idorder, products_idproduct AS idproduct, pieces FROM orders_products WHERE orders_idorder=1;
```

Then I **merge the results** in a single array and use it to display the complete list of products with the pieces ordered for each one. The final result is something like this:

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
| idorder | idproduct | description  | price | pieces |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
|       1 |         1 | Product 1    | 10.20 |      2 |
|       1 |         2 | Product 22   | 11.00 |   NULL |
|       1 |         3 | Product 333  | 19.22 |   NULL |
|       1 |         4 | Product 4444 |  9.20 |   NULL |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+
```

***Note***: In the above example there are 4 records in the *products* table and just 1 record in the *orders-products* table (it has idorder=1, idproduct=1 and pieces=2).
-> Here you can find the [SQL Dump](http://www.m4ss.net/test.sql) to test the queries.


Merging arrays built from 2 queries is the best way?
**I can do it with a single query?**
What do you think about the performance?

Comment: I am a little confused about what you are looking for.  Do you want a single query to show all of the products, with quantities ordered, given a single order id?

Comment: What information does `pieces` contain? Is it just the number of entries in the `products` table corresponding to a given order?

Comment: @willOEM yes. And then I would like to understand what is the best way.
jwd yes, it is an integer number of products ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally letting the databse optimize the merge will be better than what you can do in code. The db is usually better at sorting too.

How you structure the query depends on your desired result set. If you want all products regardless of whether they appear in the orders table then you'd use an OUTER JOIN otherwise an INNER JOIN would filter out products that have never been ordered.

If you give us your desired results for some sample data we might be able to help you with the query, but give it a shot yourself first.

```
set @searchOrderId = 1;
select ifnull(op.orders_idorder, @searchOrderId) AS idOrder,
    p.idproduct,
    p.description,
    p.price,
    op.pieces
from products p
left join orders_products op on op.products_idproduct = p.idproduct
where ifnull(op.orders_idorder, @searchOrderId) = @searchOrderId ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a04ad/17) I was playing with to test it.

Comment: Please, write here the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can get the information using a single query by JOINing the tables together. Is it what you're having troubles with?

Comment: Please, write here the query. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like WillOEM already wrote that query for you. I would have written it the same way.

Comment: Read my comment above, it doesn't work correctly. Now I added the SQL dump to test your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in general, executing a single query to retrieve the results will perform better than executing two queries and merging the results.  It is impossible to say what the ideal plan for execution is, given the information provided.  Table sizes, architecture, etc will play a role.

For retrieving all of the products from a single order, try:

```
select
    o.idorder,
    p.idproduct,
    p.description,
    p.price,
    op.pieces
from
    orders o
    inner join orders_products op
        on o.idorder = op.orders_idorder
    inner join products p
        on op.products_idproduct = p.idproduct
where
    o.idorder = 1
```

Comment: Thanks willOEM, I tried your query but it returns only 1 record (idproduct=1), the only one that has a match in the table products. I understand what you means about performance, I agree.

Comment: Now I added the SQL dump to test your queries.

Comment: This query will only return records for which the order includes products that exist in the products table.  You should avoid putting product_ids in the orders_products table, which do not exist in products.  The IDs in orders_products should be foreign keys that reference the parent tables, and this reference should be enforced.

Comment: There are not _"product_ids in the orders-products table, which do not exist in products"_ . In the orders-products table I put 1 record for any product ordered. It is the right way to manage products ordered. Do you have another schema/solution to manage them?
Please, get my dump to understand what i mean.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still a little confused.  So the output you are looking for is like what you have in your example above?  You want, given an order ID, a list of ALL products (included in the order or not) and the quantity of those products in the order?

Comment: Yes, a list of ALL products (included in the order or not) and the quantity for the products included in the order (the records stored in _orders_product_). The final result above is what I create now merging arrays (the first column idorder is to explain better what i means but is useless because I filter orders by idorder=1).

Comment: I updated my answer with a query that will give you the output you display above.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you wanted a LEFT JOIN from Products table into Orders_Products. This will give you result you're looking for.